# $k$-forms: What does $u^\times$ in $\omega_1 := \langle u,\cdot \rangle = \det(u^\times,\cdot)$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, exterior-derivative

> Consider the following $k$-forms $\omega_k$ in $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ (for $U$ open):
> \begin{align}
> &\omega_0 = f\\
> &\omega_1 := \langle u,\cdot \rangle = \det(u^\times,\cdot)\\
> &\omega_2 := f \cdot \det
> \end{align}
>
> Find relations between $u,u^\times$ and $f$, if $d\omega_0  = \omega_1$, and if $d\omega_1 = \omega_2$.
>
> **Remark:** $d\omega_k$ means the exterior derivative, which we defined as
>
> $$d(fdx^I) = df \wedge dx^I $$
>
> , where $x^1,\ldots,x^m$ are local coordinates and $df$ is the differential of $f$.

What I do not understand here is what $u^\times$ is supposed to mean here, and I can not find this in my notes either. Does anyone happen to know what this is supposed to mean?

Comment: Based on the line "Find relations between $u$,$u^\times$ and..." I would say that $u^\times$ isn't defined yet, but that you need to come up with a definition so that $\langle u, \cdot \rangle = \mathrm{det} (u^\times, \cdot )$ is true.